# How to display Thumbnail image in Google SpreadSheet if i have a link to the thumbnail image using Google App Script?

Tags: google-sheets

I am implementing the Google Apps Script and trying to display data in the Google Spread Sheet . I am able to display textual data properly, but i have a thumbnail URL of a video which i want to display in the spread sheet cell. i.e. i want to display the thumbnail image corresponding to  a URL i have in my java script variable / object.

I am also referring the link, ([https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#writing]).

How can i do this. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the script to write a formula to a cell as in =IMAGE(url)

Comment: Is there a way to get the thumbnail from another cell? This didn't work: `=IMAGE(C2)`

Comment: see here on setting formulas with references https://stackoverflow.com/a/55566806

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
 =HYPERLINK(url, image(url))
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

I used `=image("path to the thumbnail")` and assigned this to a cell, and now the thumbnail is appearing in the Google Spreadsheet.