# How to display Image from URL in Google Sheets? (and apply it to multiple rows)

Tags: google-sheets

So I created a list of members in Google Sheets, each member having a profile image, name, location, etc.

I exported this list from import.io, a data extraction tool. The only problem is that when I export it, I get the profile image url for each member, instead of getting the image itself as a thumbnail.

Someone asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159715/how-to-display-thumbnail-image-in-google-spreadsheet-if-i-have-a-link-to-the-thu). I tried using the =image("url") function and it worked, I can see the image.

What I want is a simple way of applying this function to the 200 cells I have that include a link to an image.

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I just found out about superuser.com thank to you :)

Answer (score 12):

=image() works with Arrayformula
so if your image urls are in rows, starting in cell A1, ending in cell A2, formula in B1 would be `=Arrayformula(image(A1:A2))`.

Comment: This works, but let's say I want it more dynamic i.e I do not know how many rows I will have?

Comment: @Mirko You just have to remove the number of the second parameter like this `=Arrayformula(image(A1:A))`

Answer (score 0):

Just worked for me.

I created a new column to insert the array formula and referenced the column with the urls.

Answer (score 0):

I have converted url to image using =image("url",1) and diplayed the image,
but i want to convert displayed image let's say image("https//https://www.contextures.com/images/functions/address03b.png",1) to url once again for other use case,how to do that.