# Refer to a relative cell within a formula set by apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, setvalue

I'm attempting to have GAS set formulas into various cells in my spreadsheet.

This works:

```
sheet1.getRange(rowID, 14).setValue("=iferror(vlookup(M2,'sheet2'!C:O,13,false),\"\")");
```

But I need the row in the formula to be relative (not always M2).

I thought this would work:

```
sheet1.getRange(rowID, 14).setValue("=iferror(vlookup(M" & rowID & ",'sheet2'!C:O,13,false),\"\")");
```

But it pastes a 0 in the cell.  What's up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
getRange(rowID, 14).setValue("=iferror(vlookup(M" + rowID + ",'sheet2'!C:O,13,false),\"\")");
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `.setValue()` method, use the `.setFormulaR1C1()` method.
That will allow you to reference a relative location from the starting reference point of where your range it currently set to.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getActiveSheet();

  sheet1.getRange(1, 1).setValue(10);
  sheet1.getRange(2, 2).setFormulaR1C1("=R[-1]C[-1] + 15");
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the following blog about using [Spreadsheet relative cell references](http://dsernst.com/2015/05/29/spreadsheet-relative-cell-references/).

Try the use of the indirect function. It will helps you to automatically generate the next cell in a relative way. Let me know how you go with it.